# Cannot access clearHighlightedDates() in Times-Square CalendarPickerView

Tags: android, android-calendar

Using through Gradle compile **com.squareup:android-times-square:1.5.0@aar**

```
//this works - where calendar is instance of CalendarPickerView
calendar.highlightDates(higlightedDateList);

//this doesn't work -- Cannot resolve 'clearHighlightedDates()'
calendar.clearHighlightedDates();
```

For now I am re-initializing the calendar again

Comment: Weird. What does IDE suggest with `clearHighlightedDates()`? The method exists in the said class. You must be doing something wrong, or you might try Gradle sync (that Google Chrome-like icon at the top of Android Studio).

Comment: yes it does exist in the said class. yes i did the gradle sync already. As posted above it still cannot be resolve. Will keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with your import. Trying declaring your `CalendarPickerView` as following:

```
com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView myCalendarPickerVew;
```

Comment: In that case , my friend, why would calendar.highlightDates(higlightedDateList);                                                       work ?

Comment: Then why is `clearHighlightedDates()` giving you **Cannot resolve** error? Hold on, does it throw exception (crash the app) or your IDE is giving you an error (and a red underline below the call)? Also state which IDE and version you're using.

Comment: @chaitanyad what was the cause? Please mention as it may help others.